# DataFrame How to vectorize this for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help vectorizing this `for` loop.
i couldn't come up with my own solution.
So the general idea is that I want to calculate the number of bars since the last time the condition was true.
I have DataFrame with initial values `0` and `1` where `0` is the anchor point for counting to start and stop (0 means that the condition was met for the index in this cell).
For example inital DataFrame would look like this (I am typing only the series raw values and I am ommiting column names etc.)

```
NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
```

The output should look like  this:

```
NaN, NaN, NaN, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0
```

My current code:

```
cond_count = pd.DataFrame(index=range(cond.shape[0]), columns=range(1))
cond_count.rename(columns={0: 'Bars Since'})
cond_count['Bars Since'] = 'NaN'
cond_count['Bars Since'].iloc[indices_cond_met] = 0
cond_count['Bars Since'].iloc[indices_cond_cut] = 1
for i in range(cond_count.shape[0]):
    if cond_count['Bars Since'].iloc[i] == 'NaN'
        pass
    elif cond_count['Bars Since'].iloc[i] == 0:
        while cond_count['Bars Since'].iloc[j] != 0:
            cond_count['Bars Since'].iloc[j] = cond_count['Bars Since'].shift(1).iloc[j] + 1
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]})
df['cs'] = df['data'].le(0).cumsum()

aaa = df.groupby(['data', 'cs'])['data'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
df.loc[aaa.index[0]:, 'data'] = aaa

df = df.drop(['cs'], axis=1)#if you need to remove the auxiliary column

print(df)
```

Output

```
    data
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
7    4.0
8    0.0
9    1.0
10   2.0
11   0.0
12   1.0
13   2.0
14   3.0
15   4.0
16   5.0
17   0.0
```

Here used [le](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) to get True where 0.
Then I applied [cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), thereby marking the lines into groups.

In the list `'aaa'` applied the [grouping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to the columns `'data', 'cs'` and submitted the data to [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), where it applied `cumsum()`.
Using the first slice index: `df.loc[aaa.index[0]:, 'data']` in `loc` overwrote the rows.